# I can't set the correct size of an image

Tags: html, css, image

I can't change the size of images, I made a simple code to show this:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./assets/desktop/image-glass-and-keyboard.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJQqN.jpg) it shows a width of 400px and a height of 400px, that's good:

[image]

However, when I use [digital rulers](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/measurist/id1423823777?mt=12) (I used three digital rulers and the ruler of the [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com/) software), the values of the width and height don't match:

[image]

I'm going crazy, I don't know why this is happening. I really need help.

### EDIT

following the answers here, I'm still having problems. Let's change from px to cm, because cm is an absolute unit:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./assets/desktop/image-glass-and-keyboard.jpg" width="10cm" height="10cm">
</body>
```

The picture gets really small:

[image]

I think I'm more confused than before.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect element's way of measuring is the correct one, because CSS px is an abstract unit, it doesn't represent an actual on-screen pixel.

That image **is**  400x400 px in size

Comment: I've tried to change to cm, but it's still in the incorrect size of the picture

Answer (score 0):

#### `px` is not an absolute unit

You can convert the unit to `cm` with the use of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) by multiplying the number of pixels by the ratio of centimeters in a pixel (pixels * `0.026458333333333334`) to get a real width of 400 pixels:

```css
img{
  width: calc(400 * 0.026458333333333334 * 1cm);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
```

<sup>`* 1cm` is required to convert the unit to `cm`</sup>

This is because `cm` is an absolute unit, which, as [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) states:

> ...will appear as exactly that size (within the precision of the hardware and software).

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm still facing problems with the size of the image